# Error Transpiling Babel/React (Unknown Option)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

Getting the following error when trying to run webpack:
Command: `webpack -d --watch`

.babelrc:

```
{
 "presets" : ["es2015", "react", "stage-2"],
 "plugins" : ["transform-flow-comments"]
}
```

webpack config:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var FlowBabelWebpackPlugin = require('flow-babel-webpack-plugin');

var config = {
  plugins: [
    new FlowBabelWebpackPlugin(),
  ],
  entry: ['./src/app'],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',

  },
   module : {
    loaders : [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'style!css?modules',
        include: /flexboxgrid/,
      },
      { 
        test: /\.js$/,
        loaders: ['babel'],
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        loader: "style-loader!css-loader!less-loader"
      }
    ]
  }
};

module.exports = config;

ERROR in ./src/app.js
Module build failed: ReferenceError: [BABEL] /Users/ user/gocode/src/github.com/natdm/mobilebid/frontend_v2/src/app.js: Unknown option: /Users/user/gocode/src/github.com/natdm/mobilebid/frontend_v2/node_modules/react/react.js.Children. Check out http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/options/ for more information about options.

A common cause of this error is the presence of a configuration options object without the corresponding preset name. Example:

Invalid:
  `{ presets: [{option: value}] }`
Valid:
  `{ presets: [['presetName', {option: value}]] }`
```

It's telling me I have invalid preset options, but I don't have any, and have never had any, and all of a sudden it's breaking. What do I have to update/change to get this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your `.babelrc` file seems to be correct just make sure you have installed

all the presets before using them via

```
  npm install babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-react babel-preset-stage-2 --save-dev
```

Comment: Yep. They were all installed. I just had to blow out node_modules and re-install and it worked. Oh Javascript.